# Is there an Excel formula to extract text found between to characters at the end of a string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to have the document number, version and file extension in their own columns.

I have a column (A) in excel that has data in the following format:

`\\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\93363348_1.pdf`

In the above,

- `93363348` = the document number
- `1` = the version
- `.pdf` = the file extension

Typically the above will be at the end of the string.

I used the below to extract the file extension.

`=REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,5),1,SEARCH(".",RIGHT(A1,5)),"")`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, now you just need another formula where you use `\ ` as delimiter and another one where you use `_` as delimiter. With this three formulas you can extract the desired parameters

Answer (score 2):

What you could try (using MS365) is:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","."),"_","."),".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>last()-3]"))
```

It will spill your thee required values over into columns. For more information about `FILTERXML()`, I'd like to refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) older post.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV I'll try that.